# I have a problem with uploading the code to my arduino nano

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

I am trying to upload this code:

```
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

To my arduino nano, and I get this message:

```
    Arduino: 1.8.13 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"

fork/exec /Users/vladimir/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++: no such file or directory
Error compiling for board Arduino Nano.


This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error usually occurs if you have a old Arduino Nano board.
Try changing the processor in the Arduino IDE
**Tools--> Processor --> ATmega328p (Old Bootloader)**
[image: Arduino IDE]

If the error persists still, try choosing the other processors in the list and upload the code.
If the code does not upload even after changing the processors in the IDE, there is a **chance** for your Arduino Nano board to be damaged.

Answer (score -1):

This error is not caused by #includes. This is caused by a glitch in the Arduino IDE or the Arduino AVR Boards installation. Maybe try reinstalling Arduino IDE